# Ikar and Tafel in bishul akum?

Tags: halacha, bishul-akum, ikar-tofel

If a non-Jew cooks a food in which there is a mixture of two foods, one of which satisfies a requirement to not be subject to *bishul akum* (let's say it is eaten raw), and one of which does not satisfy any of the requirements to not be subject to *bishul akum*, and the ingredient which is not subject to *bishul akum* is the primary ingredient, will there be an issue of *bishul akum* on the secondary ingredient?

For example, let's say that a vegetable stir-fry which contains mostly peppers (which are eaten raw) and some potatoes (which are not eaten raw) is cooked by a non-Jew.  Do the potatoes become subsumed under the umbrella of the peppers, as they would in a discussion of which *beracha* to make, or do they retain their identity and have an issue of *bishul akum* (which could then potentially create problems for the pan, and then from there to the peppers)?

If there are any technical problems with my examples, please feel free to leave me a note or ignore them.

Comment: Stir fry with peppers and potatoes? I have a culinary problem with your example:) Potatoes is probably a bad choice being the whole food type vs prep debate, but otherwise good question.

Comment: @user6591 I was wondering if anyone would worry about my recipes.

Comment: I just edited my answer. Btw, why didn't you pick pepper steak? Was there an assumption that meat can never be batul to pepper?

Comment: @user6591 There's a reason it's called pepper steak and not steak pepper.

Comment: Isn't that mashma the other way!? I would agree The meat isn't battul, just clarifying.

Comment: @user6591 No - pepper steak means it is primarily steak, and qualified by pepper.  Steak pepper would be primarily pepper, qualified by steak. Just like "yellow bag" is a bag, described as yellow.

Comment: ah gotcha. Fried chicken etc. Gut gizukt.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for two foods which are still visually independent, or would a mixture qualify? The author of the tshuva regards one ingredient as the ikur and rules accordingly.

Comment: @user6591 I'm interested in either, as long as it is _tafel_.  What are you referring to with "the tshuva"?

Comment: I meant the author of the tshuva I was reading, but I guess there was no way for you to know that:)

Comment: @user6591 I've been trying to hide the fact that I'm telepathic, so I had to go through the motions of asking you.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** The Rivash at the end of his tshuva #28 mentions a food called זיבליה which is made of flour and honey. He writes that he thinks it is not subject to the prohibition of bishul akum, because the honey is the main ingredient, כי אומרים שהדבש עקר, and that is not subject to the prohibition as it is eaten raw. 
*End edit*

There is an argument between the Mechaber and Ramma in siman 112 siff 6 concerning bread from a non Jewish baker, in a place where the practice is to be lenient and eat that type of bread.

The Mechaber says
אפי' הוא נלוש בביצים או שביצים טוחים על פניו מותר 
We find that the egg coating is allowed even though eggs are subject to the איסור of בישול עכום as we see in siman 113 siff 14.

The Ramma argues and from his logic it is clear how this sheds light on your question  הגה: ויש אוסרים בפת שביצים טוחים על פניו משום שהן בעין ואינם בטלים לגבי פת ויש בהם משום בשולי עובד כוכים. וכן נוהגין.

The Ramma says the egg coating is not batul because the egg coating is to a degree independent from the bread as it is ׳בעין׳.

Seemingly any food which does not maintain it's visual independence will be battul according to all.

Comment: The Rivash's wording כי אומרים Is interesting. I wonder how this plays out with Twizzlers?  If you make a shehakol there's no issue of bishul akum, but if you make a mezonos there is?

Comment: My Rav (on this matter) says to make a shehakol even though the main ingredient is wheat because it is מעשה קדרה. He has actually visited licorice factories and thought the Bracha was Mezonos before he saw how it is made. So Shehakol may not be a statement about the main ingredient.

Comment: @Yishai Interesting. That is actually interesting in light of this Rivash earlier in the tshuva. In the Twizzlers making process is it הרתיח ולבסוף הדביק? We asked Reb Dovid Feinstein and he was very adamant to make a mezonos. The only factor he seemed to keep mentioning was that the main ingredient is flour.

Comment: @Yishai what does it mean to make a shehakol because it is מעשה קדרה?  http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%96_%D7%90 - מעשה קדרה is mezonos...

Comment: @yEz, this was years ago, don't remember the details, but it was like user6591 said, they destroy the wheat before reconstituting it. One Rabbi I know thinks that all commercial breakfast cereal should is in that situation. It is the nature of modern high processed foods.

Comment: @user6591, Reb Feinstein is a tremendous Talmid Chacham, and many pasken that it is Mezonos, but that is why I go with this Rav (who is also no slouch) - he is an expert in food manufacturing and has observed it many times.

Comment: @user6591 I'm not gonna get in to the twizzlers question.  We had a big argument about it when we learned kol sheyesh bo.  None of us could believe what the other was saying.

Comment: @Yishai Isn't this machlokes across the boards between chassidish poskim and litvishe ones (in the name of Rabbi Feinstein alav hashalom). Ground reconstituted anything gets a shehakol from chassidim, and a haadama or whatever is applicable according to the litvishe (I.e. yeshivishe) ones?  And I didn't mean to put you on the spot with this psak, just thought we were swapping twizzler Rebi stories:)

Comment: @user6591, this Rav isn't Chassidish, but yeah, it's possible if Reb Dovid Feinstein saw the process he would stick with the psak. No way of knowing. (Odd thing to have a Chassidish/Litvish divide over, we aren't talking molten steel here!)

Comment: @Yishai as the story goes Reb Moshe used to rule to make haadama on reconstituted potatoes. Then someone brought a bowl of it into the beis medrash (this is not a chidush if you know anything about MTJ) and asked him what bracha to make. He said Haadama. Then they divulged the secret that it was reconstituted. To which he replied so what? look at it. Its potatoes. Now while I'm writing this I'm not sure how much that has to do with Twizzlers.